# Simple newbie help page about avoiding "Thanks"

Tags: feature-request, questions, new-users, help-center

There are several meta questions that discuss whether questions should include fluff such as salutations and thank yous, but these tend to be long pages, many of which include related topics, such as automatic text removal. They're great for moderators but overwhelming for newbies.

Is there a simple help page that concisely states that "Hi", "Thanks", etc. are not desirable in questions or answers along with a brief rationale? If not, how about creating one? It would be nice to paste the URL to that page in the comment for edits that include fluff removal.

Comment: @Catija The comments privilege page doesn't address questions, only comments. It also doesn't say anything specifically about thanks; it mentions complements, which are related to but slightly different than gratitude - probably by enough to confuse some newcomers.

Comment: Ah. Sorry. Misinterpretation of question on my part. :) Lots of people post "thanks" as a comment. :P

Comment: The canonical one is *[Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950)*.

Answer (score 5):

It's the third section of [`/help/behavior`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).

You can create a magic link in comments with `[help/behavior]`.

Comment: `[help/behavior]` covers signature, taglines, and greetings, but is silent about "Thanks", which might explain why Google couldn't find the page for me (but instead happily found plenty of duplicate meta posts). :-( The absence of guidance regarding "Thanks" seems to be an omission ripe for confusion, given the existence of the "Be nice" section.

Comment: I'm afraid that's as good as it gets for the moment. It might be worth a [tag:feature-request] to expand that section of the Help Center.

Comment: Agreed. I tagged this question with `feature-request`.

Comment: No, @Edward. Al means that you should open a separate FR on this.

Comment: As suggested, I added a [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283094/167867).

Answer (score 0):

Were you looking for something similar to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328379)?<sup>1</sup>

It's a FAQ proposal on Meta Stack Overflow. Since the commumity seems to agree with [its answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328380) (what else can a score above 15 suggest?), linking to it when editing out thanks should be fine.

<sup>1 - I'm the author of the thing. Please warn
 me with a comment if I seem to promote it too much.</sup>

Comment: Great resource, thank you!  Not sure why this answer is getting downvoted.   Oh well.

Comment: @downvoters I suppose you voted this down because it looks like some sort of spam. How can I make it less spammy?

Comment: It might be getting downvoted because what was asked for was a help page, and this is a question/answer.

Comment: Nonono, referencing an other post of yours within Stack Exchange is  certainly not spam. The downvotes are here not because your answer looks spammy (it doesn't).