# Add help center guidance about saying thanks

Tags: feature-request, comments, questions, new-users, help-center-proposed

Suggestion: In [help/behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/behavior), add guidance about not writing "Thanks", etc. Include a brief rationale, and mention that accepting an answer and upvoting are the preferred means of saying thanks.

Background: There is currently no guidance regarding "Thanks", "Thanks in advance", etc. for questions or comments. The closest is [privileges/comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), which is specific to comments. It suggests avoiding compliments ("+1, great answer!"), but says nothing about gratitude, which may be different enough from a compliment to confuse new users, especially in light of the section above on being nice.

[Related discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283070/167867)

Comment: The canonical one is *[Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950)*.

Comment: @PeterMortensen [Should 'Hi'...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/167867) is a great discussion, but is 13,314 words - waaaaay too heavy for a new user. This feature request is about something, simple, light, and accessible.

Comment: This is question is related to [Simple newbie help page about avoiding “Thanks”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283070/167867), but is a specific feature request, whereas the other page is a more general discussion and question about what currently exists. The consensus seemed to be that the feature request belongs in a separate question. Assuming that's correct, this question should not be marked as duplicate.